# Expo SDK 36, a generic resolution for "componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed, and is not recommended for use" errors

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo, componentwillreceiveprops, react-native-safe-area-view

When I run `expo start` the warning I receive is:

```
Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed, and is not recommended for use. 
...

* Rename componentWillReceiveProps to UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps to suppress this warning in non-strict mode. In React 17.x, only the UNSAFE_ name will work. To rename all deprecated lifecycles to their new names, you can run `npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles` in your project source folder.

Please update the following components: SafeView, Transitioner
- node_modules/expo/build/environment/muteWarnings.fx.js:18:23 in warn
...
```

I know this is a warning and is not seen in production mode, but in order not to miss other possible warnings I want to get rid of this.

I am not using `componentWillReceiveProps` but the dependencies `expo` has are using.

- The suggested `npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles` checks only the codes that I wrote, not the ones coming from `node_modules`.
- And the suggestion `Please update the following components: SafeView, Transitioner`is not applicable because they are not from the components that I included but from `expo` and its dependencies where the major one is the `react-native` itself.

As a solution is there any method to get rid of this warning in a generic way? Else, is there a method to get rid for only `SafeView` and `Transitioner` components (i.e. react-native-safe-area-view react-navigation react-navigation-stack packages) ?

Comment: I'm not sure its possible to disable the error completely, however its is actually a warning and this warning won't show up in the production build.

Comment: Thanks Danny. That I already know. But still I wanna get rid of it proper way.

Comment: there is an open issue on react native https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22186 perhaps this is related.

Answer (score 0):

Seems being (as of March 2nd, 2020) addressed within SDK 38.

Pls refer to:

1. https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/5763
2. https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/7227
3. https://github.com/orgs/expo/projects/6